# Rails 6, override @rails/ujs confirm to show modal

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootbox

I have a Rails 6 application, using Webpacker and @rails/ujs. I'm trying to override the Rails.confirm method to show a bootbox-js modal.

```js
import Rails from "@rails/ujs";

Rails.confirm = function(message, el) {
  bootbox.alert({
    message,
    callback: function() {
      console.log('Callback');
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

I can't understand what to put in the callback function to proceed with the default link behaviour, given that it can be or not be a remote request.
By default rails_ujs use a blocking 'confirm' function, but it cannot be done with bootboxjs.

In the above code the modal is shown correctly. I don't want a jQuery AJAX call in the callback but the default Rails behaviour.

Here is the source coffe in Rails [GitHub Source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/app/assets/javascripts/rails-ujs/features/confirm.coffee)

Comment: Bootbox primarily is an engine for creating Bootstrap modals on the fly. Bootstrap modals are just positioned div elements, so there's no real way to mimic the same behavior as a native alert/confirm/prompt dialog. If `<dialog>` ever gets to the point where it's supported in most browsers, I'll update Bootbox to use it, but that seems a ways off, at the moment. [dialog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) is the only element that would work, here.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, given that we cannot mimic the native function, the question remain valid, how I can achieve the "same" behaviour inside the callback with rails/ujs? Maybe it's simply not meant to be used like that...

Comment: I can't answer that. I don't know anything about rails/ujs. Possibly something involving async/await, but that assumes ES7 or better as a minimum (and I haven't really dug much into that, yet).